# Unsupported column datatype

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have Oracle 12C installed in my system. I have created one SP which is returning a Table When I am trying to execute it in SQL Developer, it is giving me correct result, But When I am calling it from my DOTNET application it is giving me the error --"Unsupported column datatype". I am trying to fill dataset using Data adapter. To check I commented all the code in the procedure and returned the table using below code.

```
Declare  
rc sys_refcursor;  
Begin  
   OPEN rc FOR SELECT 'Sayam' AS "Error" FROM dual;  
   SYS.DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT (rc, TRUE) ;  
END;
```

But Still the problem was same. Below is the trace of the same.

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException was caught
>       HResult=-1450
>       Message=Unsupported column datatype
>       Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver   ErrorCode=-1450   DataSource=""   Number=-1450   Procedure=""
>   StackTrace:
>          at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnectionImpl
>   connImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo cachedParamMetadata, Boolean&
>   bMetadataModified, Int32 arrayBindCount, ColumnDescribeInfo&
>   paramMetaData, Object& paramValue, Boolean isEFSelectStatement)
>          at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.InitializeParamInfo(ICollection
>   paramColl, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo[]
>   cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bMetadataModified, Boolean
>   isEFSelectStatement, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper&
>   marshalBindValuesHelper)
>          at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ProcessParameters(OracleParameterCollection
>   paramColl, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo[]
>   cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bBindMetadataModified, Boolean
>   isEFSelectStatement, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper&
>   marshalBindValuesHelper, Boolean& bAllInputBinds)
>          at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String
>   commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType
>   commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl,
>   OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64
>   clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]
>   scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection&
>   bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64&
>   internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML,
>   Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
>          at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean
>   requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet
>   dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable,
>   IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
>          at DataAccessLayer.DataAccessService.OracleGetData_Load(String SPName, XElement QueryParam, Exception& e, Boolean bFlag) in
>   d:\Sayam\April\Multiplay\DataAccessLayer\DataAccessLayer\DAS.cs:line
>   187

I have tried this link also.

[Unsupported column datatype ODP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489730/unsupported-column-datatype-odp-net)

Please let me know if I need to change any where.

```
 using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
```

and the code goes

```
                if (this.ConOracle.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    ConOracle.Open();
                oraCmd.Connection = ConOracle;
                oraCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                oraCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                OracleGetQuery(ref oraCmd, SPName.Split('.')[1],QueryParam);

                using (OracleDataAdapter oraDA = new OracleDataAdapter(oraCmd))
                { oraDA.Fill(ds); }
```

Thanks
Sayam

Comment: Maybe show your c# code? and the actual procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  I searchedfor the days and find that I need to install the package from the below link and  it worked fine.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Thanks